# Laravel mix, How to set up different css and js for frontend and admin sections?

Tags: javascript, css, webpack, laravel-mix

I want to have admin and user parts of css and js in separate files. 
What is the best way to do that? 
I set: `

```js
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .js('resources/js/admin/admin.js', 'public/js/admin')
    .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
    .sass('resources/sass/admin.scss', 'public/css/admin');
```

` but how should my resources folder structure should be to prevent everything from duplicates? Any guide how to minimize, separate or restructure my files to get better performance readability?
How to set up laravel mix to build 2 js and 2 css for different usage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is what I do using [minimist](https://www.npmjs.com/package/minimist). This works as of Laravel v8 and Laravel Mix v5.

#### File Structure

```
resources
├── js
│   ├── app.js
│   └── admin.js
└── sass
    ├── app.scss
    └── admin.scss
```

#### Install Package

```sh
# NPM
% npm install minimist --save-dev

# YARN
% yarn add minimist --dev
```

#### webpack.mix.js

```js
const mix = require('laravel-mix');
const argv = require('minimist')(process.argv.slice(2));

const src = {
  user: {
    js: 'resources/js/app.js',
    sass: 'resources/sass/app.scss'
  },
  admin: {
    js: 'resources/js/admin.js',
    sass: 'resources/sass/admin.scss'
  }
}
const dest = {
  js: 'public/js',
  sass: 'public/css'
}
// For User
if (argv.user) {
    mix.js(src.user.js, dest.js) // Output: public/js/app.js
       .sass(src.user.sass, dest.sass); // Output: public/css/app.css
}
// For Admin
else if (argv.admin) {
    mix.js(src.admin.js, dest.js) // Output: public/js/admin.js
       .sass(src.admin.sass, dest.sass); // Output: public/css/admin.css
}
// Both
else {
    mix.js(src.user.js, dest.js)
       .js(src.admin.js, dest.js)
       .sass(src.user.sass dest.sass)
       .sass(src.admin.sass, dest.sass);
}
```

#### Run Script

```
# NPM
% npm run watch --user
% npm run watch --admin

# YARN
% yarn watch --user
% yarn watch --admin
```

You can replace the `watch` script with `dev` or `prod`.

**Note**: Laravel Mix still keeps watching all files under `resources`, executes compilation whenever any file under the directory is changed.